# Query performance decreased

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql

I have a query like below:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,unit1,unit2,unit3,unit4,unit5
  FROM (select x.*,
               to_number(substr(it_specs,instr(it_specs,',',1,1)+1,instr(it_specs,',',1,2)-instr(it_specs,',',1,1)-1)) unit1,
               to_number(substr(it_specs,instr(it_specs,',',1,2)+1,instr(it_specs,',',1,3)-instr(it_specs,',',1,2)-1)) unit2,
               to_number(substr(it_specs,instr(it_specs,',',1,3)+1,instr(it_specs,',',1,4)-instr(it_specs,',',1,3)-1)) unit3,
               to_number(substr(it_specs,instr(it_specs,',',1,4)+1,instr(it_specs,',',1,5)-instr(it_specs,',',1,4)-1)) unit4,
               to_number(substr(it_specs,instr(it_specs,',',1,5)+1,instr(it_specs,',',1,6)-instr(it_specs,',',1,5)-1)) unit5
          from (select a.*,
                       (select IT_PKG.IT_SPECS(charges, TRUNC(usrdate), 'N')
                          from dual) AS it_Specs
                  from tabl1 A
                  ORDER BY a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5) x) a,
       tabl2 B
  WHERE A.CA = B.CA
  group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
           unit1, unit2, unit3, unit4, unit5
```

The number of records tabl1 ranges from 100 to 25000. The number of records in tabl2 are one thousands.
There are two table involved in function IT_SPECS. Each have half million records.
This query was working fine for few months with no performance issue.It can be seen from below trace:

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.01       0.01          0          2          0           0
Fetch     6177      0.90       1.04        375        761          0       12351
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total     6179      0.92       1.06        375        763          0       12351
```

But performance decreased significantly apparently for no reason.

```
 call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.02       0.03          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.02       0.10        239        153          0           0
Fetch      107      5.58      26.54        680      70660          0       10637
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total      109      5.64      26.67        919      70813          0       10637
```

My question why I am getting high query value and elapsed time is also high?
The fetch count is second case is less but it has no impact on performance.

Explain Plan:
[image]

Plan when query performing :

```
Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
     11030      11030      11030  FAST DUAL  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=9295 us cost=2 size=0 card=1)
     12300      12300      12300  HASH GROUP BY (cr=774 pr=375 pw=375 time=738182 us cost=216 size=2290 card=2)
     12613      12613      12613   HASH JOIN  (cr=774 pr=0 pw=0 time=545344 us cost=215 size=14622795 card=12771)
        13         13         13    VIEW  index$_join$_005 (cr=6 pr=0 pw=0 time=2267 us cost=3 size=104 card=13)
        13         13         13     HASH JOIN  (cr=6 pr=0 pw=0 time=2254 us)
        13         13         13      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN C_TYP_UK1 (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=68 us cost=1 size=104 card=13)(object id 81097)
        13         13         13      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN C_TYP_X1 (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=51 us cost=1 size=104 card=13)(object id 390320)
     12613      12613      12613    VIEW  (cr=768 pr=0 pw=0 time=520833 us cost=211 size=14520627 card=12771)
     12613      12613      12613     TABLE ACCESS FULL tabl1 (cr=752 pr=0 pw=0 time=43361 us cost=211 size=13779909 card=12771)

********************************************************************************
```

Plan when performance issue occurred:

```
Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
     13676      13676      13676  FAST DUAL  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=26975 us cost=2 size=0 card=1)
     13754      13754      13754  HASH GROUP BY (cr=109351 pr=1072 pw=435 time=31552012 us cost=273 size=2290 card=2)
     15875      15875      15875   HASH JOIN  (cr=109351 pr=637 pw=0 time=37695338 us cost=271 size=20364970 card=17786)
        13         13         13    VIEW  index$_join$_005 (cr=6 pr=0 pw=0 time=5159 us cost=3 size=104 card=13)
        13         13         13     HASH JOIN  (cr=6 pr=0 pw=0 time=5142 us)
        13         13         13      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN C_TYP_UK1 (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=175 us cost=1 size=104 card=13)(object id 81097)
        13         13         13      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN C_TYP_X1 (cr=3 pr=0 pw=0 time=152 us cost=1 size=104 card=13)(object id 390320)
     15875      15875      15875    VIEW  (cr=109345 pr=637 pw=0 time=37587033 us cost=268 size=20222682 card=17786)
     15875      15875      15875     TABLE ACCESS FULL tabl1 (cr=952 pr=632 pw=0 time=50917 us cost=268 size=19191094 card=17786)

********************************************************************************
```

**This query run with good performance for months. Actually I am more interested to know why performance degraded after few months and why we are getting high query value?**

Comment: Why do us select 5 times exactly the same column?

Comment: Your query looks very strange, you select 5 times exactly the same column (unit). This column is neither selected in the main query nor it is used in any WHERE clause. Why do you select it at all? Maybe you removed a lot of stuff from your orginal query, this example looks useless.

Comment: Can you please post the query plan.                             Also, can you confirm if any changes have been made to the IT_PKG.IT_specs or any change in the selctivity of the indexes defined on the underlying tables .

Comment: I have updated the query as per first two comments.

Comment: When was the last time statistics were gathered on TABL1, TABL2, and any tables referenced by IT_PKG.IT_SPECS?

Comment: TABL1 is changed with every execution of query and average records in this table about 10K. TABL2 contains only few thousand records that rarely updated

Comment: @Wernfried makes a good point - the computed columns `unit1`, `unit2`, `unit3`, `unit4`, and `unit5` appear to produced exactly the same value as they are all computed in exactly the same way. Is this a typo?

Comment: If you have the tuning pack licensed, use `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_awr(sql_id => '<your sql id>'));` to determine if the explain plans have changed over time.

Comment: You may also want to use SQL Monitoring to find out exactly which step of the execution plan is causing a problem.  Try: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '<your sql id>', type => 'active') from dual;`.  That will likely tell you *exactly* what is taking so long, and then you may be able to determine what changed.

Comment: @BobJarvis it was a typo and corrected. I have updated question to make it more clear

Comment: @jonearles I have updated question to make it more clear

Comment: Performance probably degraded because the plans changed.  But we can't dig much deeper unless we know exactly how the plans changed.  And it would also help if we knew exactly what was slow in the current query.  Then we could perhaps figure out what bad decision the optimizer is making and why.  Also, since you have the trace you can also determine if the problem is from the recursive SQL inside the package - there should be another relevant query in the tkprof output.

Comment: @jonearles I added plan when working fine and plan when we have performance issue. But apparently there is no change in plan.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the execution plan which was executed in earlier times?
First of all, gather table statistics of involved tables.

Don't use `(select IT_PKG.IT_SPECS(charges, TRUNC(usrdate), 'N') from dual) AS it_Specs`, simply do `IT_PKG.IT_SPECS(charges, TRUNC(usrdate), 'N') AS it_Specs`.

**UPDATE**
Does this query now returns desired result?

```
WITH x AS
    (SELECT ca,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,IT_PKG.IT_SPECS(charges, TRUNC(usrdate), 'N') AS it_Specs
    FROM tabl1)
a AS 
    (SELECT x.*, 
        TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(it_specs,INSTR(it_specs,',',1,1)+1,INSTR(it_specs,',',1,2)-INSTR(it_specs,',',1,1)-1)) unit
    FROM x)
SELECT a.*, 
    unit AS unit1, unit AS unit2, unit AS unit3, unit AS unit4, unit AS unit5 -- always the same
FROM a
    JOIN tabl2 B ON A.CA = B.CA
GROUP BY col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,unit1,unit2,unit3,unit4,unit5
ORDER BY col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

Comment: Wernfried Thank you for your input. Actually I am more interested to know why above query get slow.

Comment: The `(select ... from dual)` is probably a good thing as it will enable [scalar subquery caching](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some issues where Oracle repeats the function call many, many times, even when it is 'just' a selection from `dual`.

Try to move the query to a `with`. See [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php).

Comment: During we tried with version but that had some issues and was rejected. The above query was working perfectly fine for months but then we got this performance issue.

Comment: Waht do you mean by "had some issues"?

Comment: As compare to performance and there was some limitation according to our requirement

Comment: @QMG: still not very specific. Did you test the `with` statement itself. How did that perform? And the other part of the query, did you run that on itself?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Don't forget about scalar subquery caching.  The `(select ... from dual)` is probably a good thing.

Comment: @jonearles: you are right but I have seen some circumstances where the optimizer mistakes itself and fires the pl/sql block for each row. In specific with ANSI joins. Just as a hint to try.

Comment: Hmm, to be more specific Oracle tends to switch from just executing a function call a few times into executing it for every element bubbling up in the execution plan. Not uncommon that there are "suddenly" millions of executions. Do not use with alone but also add /*+ no_merge */ to master select and materialize (undocumented) to the select in the with. But to be honest I would strongly suggest rewriting the query first. Remember 90% of performance bugs are application bugs and this query is badly written and hardly readable. Making it readable probably pops up a few bugs already.

Comment: @PatrickHofman this query works with good performance for months. I am more interested to know the reason of its slowness